# .tolowerCase() Where should I put it?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a command handler but I don't know where should I put the `.toLowerCase()` or how should I put it.

Here is my command handler:

```
client.on("message", async message => {
    if(message.author.bot || message.channel.type === "dm") return;
    
    let prefix = (";");
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let cmd = messageArray[0];
    let args = messageArray.slice(1)
    
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    let commandfile = client.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)) || client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)))
    if(commandfile) commandfile.run(client,message,args)
});
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: for the commands to work if someone types ;eXamPle etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `.toLowerCase()` function, as the name suggests, just converts a string to lower case. So I could do like:

```
let myString = 'DiFfErEnT cAsE'
let lowerCaseString = myString.toLowerCase();
console.log(lowerCaseString)// <-- returns "different case"
```

So, in your command handler, you can make the variable `cmd` always be lowercase, by editing the line

```
let cmd = messageArray[0];
```

to be:

```
let cmd = messageArray[0].toLowerCase();
```

and that should do what you're looking for. You would obviously have to make sure all of your command name and command aliases are all in lower case, otherwise it would be impossible to run the command. Hope that answers your question!